# Is it possible to map object value types in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

For example, I have a function of the following form:

```
function wrap<T>(item: T): W<T> {
}
interface W<T> {
  item: T;
}
```

Is it possible to write function (`mapValues`), that will transform given object values by applying this `wrap` function and return properly typed object? I understand how to write the actual function (lodash's `_.mapValues` will work fine), but I don't know if it is possible to apply proper types.

Is it possible to write `mapValues` function so the following will compile?

```
interface Before {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}

interface After {
  a: W<number>;
  b: W<string>;
}

let obj1: Before = { a: 1, b: "2" };
let obj2: After = mapValues(obj1);

function typecheck_number(arg: number) {}
function typecheck_string(arg: string) {}
typecheck_number(obj2.a.item);
typecheck_string(obj2.b.item);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one possible solution:

```
interface W<T> {
  item: T;
}
function mapValues<T>(obj: T): {[K in keyof T]: W<T[K]>} {
  // implementation
}
```

Unfortunately, similar recursive approach does not seem to be possible, but there is hope that it will be possible with type constraints from [this proposal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13257).

This link was very helpful in arriving to this solution: https://blog.mariusschulz.com/2016/05/31/type-queries-and-typeof-in-typescript

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your types in the OP are correct. `mapValues` only needs to be marked to return the type of `After`.

Here is a [TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20W%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20item%3A%20T%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Before%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20After%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20W%3CBefore%5B%22a%22%5D%3E%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20W%3CBefore%5B%22b%22%5D%3E%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20before%3A%20Before%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%201%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20'2'%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20wrap%3CT%3E(item%3A%20T)%3A%20W%3CT%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20sample%20implementation%0D%0A%2F%2F%20function%20wrap%3CT%3E(item%3A%20T)%3A%20W%3CT%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20return%20%7B%20item%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20mapValues(obj%3A%20Before)%3A%20After%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20sample%20implementation%0D%0A%2F%2F%20function%20mapValues(obj%3A%20Before)%3A%20After%20%7B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20const%20after%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20key%20in%20obj)%20%7B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20after%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%20wrap(obj%5Bkey%5D)%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20%20%20%20return%20after%20as%20After%3B%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20after%20%3D%20mapValues(before)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20typeCheck%3CT%3E(arg%3A%20T)%3A%20void%0D%0A%0D%0AtypeCheck%3Cnumber%3E(after.a.item)%3B%0D%0AtypeCheck%3Cstring%3E(after.b.item)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20out%3A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20console.log(after)%3B) that shows ur example working fine if `mapValues` was to return a type of `After`.

The properties of the mapped object are of type `Wrap<T>`.

Comment: No, the idea was to make `mapValues` generic, so it will work this way on any other interface (not only Before and After - they were here just for an example).

Comment: @Rogach Wouldln't the type declation for `mapValues` then just be `mapValues<T>(obj: any): T`?

Comment: No, because then I would need to write out `mapValues<{ prop1: T1, etc...}>()` explicitly (compiler would not be able to infer T). The idea is that return type automatically depends on argument type and type checker can provide guidance (thus helping me, the programmer, to avoid errors).